# Python: Convert XML records into consistent type irrespective of number of children/leaves

Tags: python, json, xml

I am new to XML parsing in Python. I have an input file created by another entity that I have to parse. Though I have been able to do it in multiple ways, I am struggling with a peculiar issue a solution to which I could not find. I am illustrating an example below of the sample structure that I got after converting it to JSON through `xmltodict`. I prefer working with JSON as I can load it into `pandas`, though the issue remains the same even with native XML data:

```
{
  "teams":{
    "team0":null,
    "team1":{
      "name":"john",
      "age":"20",
      "city":"sf"
    },
    "team2":{
      "name":[
        "john",
        "craig"
      ],
      "age":[
        "20",
        "22"
      ],
      "city":[
        "ny",
        "boston"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As can be seen, fields such as `name` can be `null`, `str` or even `list` depending on the number of entries. This forces me to consider data type and write code for each case. This is frustrating as, unlike the case shown here, there are several levels and the cost of programming increases exponentially. As I only get the XML as input from an external source, I cannot dictate the structure.

I would eventually need to get some information in the following format:

```
TeamName,Players,Ages,Cities
team0,,,
team1,john,20,sf
team2,john|craig,20|22,ny|boston
```

My current approach of practically using a decision tree approach depending on data type of each field is making the code look inefficient and cumbersome. Any suggestion towards solving the problem would be greatly appreciated.

PS: (Edit)

Simple example:

```
import xmltodict
import json

x ='<?xml version="1.0" ?><teams><team0></team0><team1><name>john</name><age>20</age><city>sf</city></team1><team2><name>john</name><age>20</age><city>ny</city><city>boston</city><name>craig</name><age>22</age></team2></teams>'
data = xmltodict.parse(x)
json_ob = json.dumps(data, indent = 2, separators=(',', ':'))
print(json_ob)
```

Comment: If, in fact, "the cost of programming increases exponentially", you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Question should include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What's the XML source and python code?

Comment: @LMC, added the minimal example I have shown.

Answer (score 1):

The promising approach that I found is shown below that uses conversion into frame:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x ='<?xml version="1.0" ?><teams><team0></team0><team1><name>john</name><age>20</age><city>sf</city></team1><team2><name>john</name><age>20</age><city>ny</city><city>boston</city><name>craig</name><age>22</age></team2></teams>'
>>> data = xmltodict.parse(x)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> bn = pd.DataFrame(df.teams.values.tolist())[0]
>>> pd.json_normalize(bn)
            name       age          city
0            NaN       NaN           NaN
1           john        20            sf
2  [john, craig]  [20, 22]  [ny, boston]
>>>
```

PS: Left out adding other columns and converting to csv file using `apply` method.

Comment: What are `pd` and `df`?

Comment: Added the statements for importing pandas and dataframe.